# How does Android choose among multiple access points?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have been doing a lot of research on this. Unfortunately I was not able to find how, by default, Android chooses among multiple access points.

For instance, if a user walks into a mall and there are 3 hotspots within range, how does the device select which access point to connect to?

```
-Does the device select the AP based in the order in which they are in the Wi-Fi stack? 
-Does the device select the AP based on signal strength only? 
-Does the device select the AP randomly?
```

Also, as the user physically moves from the coverage of AP A to the coverage of AP B:

```
-Does the device stay connected with AP A until it is out of range?
-Does the device transition from AP A to AP B somewhere along the way (sort of like a soft handoff)?
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good question - I'm interested in knowing the answer. However, you may have better luck over at http://android.stackexchange.com/. (This isn't directly a programming-related question.)